# Unable to map the HBase row key in HIve table effectively

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hive-serde

I have a HBase table where the rowkey looks like this.

```
08:516485815:2013 1
06:260070837:2014 1
00:338289200:2014 1
```

I create a Hive link table using the below query.

```
create external table hb
(key string,value string)
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,e:-1")
tblproperties("hbase.table.name"="hbaseTable");
```

When I query the table I get the below result

```
select * from hb;

08:516485815 1
06:260070837 1
00:338289200 1
```

This is very strange to me. Why the serde is not able to map the whole content of the HBase key? The hive table is missing everything after the second ':'

Has anybody faced a similar kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

I tried by recreating your scenario on Hbase 1.1.2 and Hive 1.2.1000,it works as expected and i am able to get the **whole rowkey from hive**.

```
hbase>   create 'hbaseTable','e'
hbase>   put 'hbaseTable','08:516485815:2013','e:-1','1'
hbase>   scan 'hbaseTable'
    ROW                                                         COLUMN+CELL
     08:516485815:2013                                          column=e:-1, timestamp=1519675029451, value=1
    1 row(s) in 0.0160 seconds
```

As i'm having 08:516485815:2013 as rowkey and i have created hive table

```
 hive> create external table hb
    (key string,value string)
    stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,e:-1")
    tblproperties("hbase.table.name"="hbaseTable");
 hive> select * from hb;
    +--------------------+-----------+--+
    |       hb.key       | hb.value  |
    +--------------------+-----------+--+
    | 08:516485815:2013  | 1         |
    +--------------------+-----------+--+
```

Can you once make sure your hbase table rowkey having the data after **second :**.

Comment: Hbase has the key like how I have mentioned.

Comment: If I follow the same step of hbase table and the hive table creation like you, I get the same result like yours. But the HBase table that I use has values as json. Dont know if that makes any difference. Also the row keys are combination of both the types i.e. `08:516485815:2013` and `08:516485815`

Comment: Could you share some sample hbase rows..scan ‘table-name’,{LIMIT=>10}